# Deutsche Wörter für zwei spezifische technische Begriffe (Programmierung): inlining, unswitching

Tags: single-word-request, technical-terminology, software

Ich muss aktuell einen Bericht für die Uni auf Deutsch formulieren.

Ich suche nach deutschen Begriffen für die folgenden zwei Wörter:

"inlining" (Den Funktionsinhalt an die Stelle des Aufrufs kopieren, siehe auch [de-wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline-Ersetzung))

"unswitching" (Konstante Bedingungen aus einer Schleife herausziehen, siehe auch [en-wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unswitching))

Insbesondere geht es um Adjektive die eine Schleife oder einen Funktionsaufruf nach dieser Transformation beschreiben. Aktuell fällt mir nur folgendes ein:

- "Die Schleife wurde erfolgreich geunswitched"
- "Der Aufruf wurde geinlined"

Gibt es hierfür schönere Alternativen?

Comment: Ist das hier mit inlining gemeint? : https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline-Ersetzung Für Unswitching nur die englische Version gefunden: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unswitching bzw in groß: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler => vielleicht in die Frage reinnehmen, damit jeder sieht, was in "ausführlich" gemeint ist?

Comment: Gute Idee, ja die beiden Begriffe meinte ich. Füge es zur Frage hinzu

Comment: Auch wenn beide Begriffe aus dem gleichen Metier stammen hilft die Beantwortung der einen Frage nicht bei der anderen, sprich, sie sind unabhängig voneinander und es sollten daher zwei Fragen gestellt werden. Wie immer in diesen Fällen kann es sein, dass eine gut beantwortet wird und die andere nicht - die gut beantwortete kann dann nicht separat als gelöst gesetzt werden und die Bewertung einer Antwort, die nur eine Frage gut beantwortet, ist auch nicht möglich. Also einen Teil bitte abtrennen und separat stellen.

Comment: Dass die Schleife einem Unswitching unterzogen wurde unterstellt, dass es erfolgreich erfolgreich war - was soll das "erfolgreich"? Betonen, welch ungeheure Leistung das war? Meine Bank schreibt mir auch immer auf die Webseite, ich hätte mich erfolgreich abgemeldet, als ob abgemeldet allein nicht genügen würde.

Comment: Ich gebe zu bedenken, das sich die englische Sprache in beiden genannten Fällen auch begeistert um ein Verb drückt (es gibt kein *to inline* oder *to unswitch*, das für diese Begrifflichkeiten verwendet würde - Deine englischen Beispiele verwenden ebenfalls Nominalisierungen). Warum willst du dann unbedingt Verben im Deutschen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meines Wissens gibt es für die meisten derartigen fachspezifischen Begriffe keine etablierte deutsche Entsprechung. Ich würde daher, wenn der anzuwendende Styleguide (noch so ein Begriff ;) ) es erlaubt, die Bedingung fallen lassen, dass es ein Adjektiv sein muss.

Dann könntest Du etwas schreiben wie

> Das Inlining des Aufrufs hat den Effekt, dass...
>
> Indem die Schleife unswitched wurde, konnte erreicht werden, dass...

Die beste Lösung dürfte aber sein, ein Äquivalent auf Deutsch zu formulieren, und zusätzlich den englischen Fachterminus anzugeben

> Dieses Problem konnte gelöst werden, indem wir den Aufruf der Funktion durch ihren Inhalt ersetzten (Inlining).
>
> Das Herausziehen der Konstante `CONST` aus der Bedingung der Schleife (Unswitching) erhöht die Lesbarkeit des Codes.

Answer (score 1):

> Insbesondere geht es um Adjektive die eine Schleife oder einen Funktionsaufruf nach dieser Transformation beschreiben

1. Die *eingebettete* Funktion
2. Die *refaktorisierte* Schleife

rein geschichtlich könnten ganz andere Begriffe entwickelt worden sein, das weiß ich nicht. So hat "embedded systems" (integrierte Systeme) zumindest eine ganz andere Bedeutung.

Man kann natürlich auch einfach nach englischem Vorbild das Nomen als *noun adjunct* wie ein Adjektiv--aber eben ungebeugt--voranstellen, also die "inline-Funktion", die "unswitched-Schleife", dann immer mit Bindestrich zum Fremdwort.